# CAML Query with multiple conditions

Tags: caml-query, caml

I'm trying to add another OR condition in my CAML Query below, but nothing seems to be working. Can someone help? Please see attached picture of the library. I am trying to get the highlighted data. Here is the CAML query. Library Name and Level stays the same. I need to grab the 1st row, 3rd and 4th row. The first attempt I am trying to get the exact person (Marshall, Kim), then I am saying give me data where Line=Pure and Any Local is Yes (not working but it should give me Sandoz, Newman), then also give me where Any Line is yes and Any Local is Yes for Packaging with Level A. (Howey, Laurel).

[image]

```
<Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
         </Eq>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Level' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>
            <And>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Line' />
                  <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
               </Eq>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Place' />
                  <Value Type='Lookup'>Vincente, New Port, CA</Value>
               </Eq>
            </And>
         </And>
 </And>
 <And>
<Or>
    <And>
      <And>
        <And>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
          </Eq>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Level' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
          </Eq>
        </And>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Line' />
          <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
        </Eq>
      </And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='AnyPlace' />
        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
</Or>
      </And>

  </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of providing so many conditions, below query can work and give you exact same results.

As per what I see in the list data you have shared, I have drafted this.

```
<Query>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
</ViewFields>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Level' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>            
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Line' />
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
                </Eq>
                <And>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLine' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq> 
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLocal' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </And>
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Please note: column names are correctly used as per your list.

If you understand the concept on how to write CAML queries, you will not need any tool. Read my blog on [understanding dynamic queries](https://www.gaurravs.com/post/understanding-dynamic-queries)

Comment: Thanks Gaurravs, I am getting "Sandoz, Newman", "Howey, Laurel" and "Shield, Brook Ann (BK)" but result should be "Marshall, Kim", "Sandoz, Newman", "Howey, Laurel"

Comment: can you try update one

Comment: Cool. Now it's working. Thank you So much.

Comment: I tried using saketa and u2u caml builder but it doesn't formulate the query like you provided. What if I want have more things to add to query? what tool can I use?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I have added a link

Comment: Thank you Gaurravs.

Comment: I tried to add OR clause so I can grab Row 2 (Pey, Lu) and Row 6 (Martino, Eric) based on Library and Level being same and "AnyLine" is set to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked.

```
<Query>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
</ViewFields>
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Library' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>Packaging</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Level' />
                <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
            </Eq>            
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Line' />
                    <Value Type='Lookup'>PURE</Value>
                </Eq>              
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='AnyLine' />
                        <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                    </Eq>                 
            </Or>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```